# Web Services with x.509 certificates. Porting C# code to Rails

Tags: c#, .net, ruby-on-rails, soap, x509

I am currently in the process of building a new web-based system in rails to replace a legacy .NET solution (stand-alone Win32 app). The system allows analysts to perform a number of actions. In many cases, the users request is actually served by a call to a third-party web-service. The web services are secured using X.509 certificates issued by the third-party. The .NET code to make the calls is below:

(In Visual Studio, I have declared a web/service reference called 'ProductionServices' at the corresponding URL)

```
X509Certificate2 c = new X509Certificate2("filepath", "password");
using (ProductionServices.Items items = new ProductionServices.Items())
{
  try
  {
   //specify client certificate if needed
   if (c != null)
   items.ClientCertificates.Add(c);

   XmlNode node = null;

   node = items.getItemList();

   XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
   xd.AppendChild(xd.ImportNode(node, true));

   .......
```

}

So, at this point we have our rails app looking nice and polished. However, I now need to replicate the .NET logic above in rails so that I can pull that web service data into my views as well. I have found very basic examples of how to do this, but never a good example using client certificates. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Net::HTTP, take a look here:

http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

and about halfway down the page there's an example entitled "SSL/HTTPS request with PEM certificate".

If you're using some kind of wrapper around Net::HTTP (HTTParty, Typhoeus, etc.) that'll depend on the library in question. Is that the case?

Comment: Ok thanks. This is a big help. One thing that I noticed though is that the example is using a PEM file, whereas my certificates are .p12. I did a little research and found that in order to use this example I need to somehow break the .p12 container file into its .key and .pem parts. Do you know if this should be done using openssl or if Net:HTTP has a more elegant out of the box way to deal with a .p12 cert?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say, I'm not familiar with that format.